# reading a binary file's contents and decrypting it

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a binary file that contains some encrypted text. Using File Open wizard, I am loading that file. When I click a button, say OK button, I want the bin file's contents to be decrypted and displayed in a read only textbox. 
Any idea on how I should go about it?

Comment: How has it been encrypted?

Comment: Need more information than "Encrypted" what algorithm have you used to encrypt the text in the file? Is the text the only part of the file? What was used to generate the file?

Comment: d bin file contains a registry key value which has already been encrypted using an algorithm. am using a code to retrieve the value of a reg key file and store it in a bin file. now i want d encrypted text within d bin file to b decrypted and displayed in the 2nd textbox. and yes, the text is d only part of d file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify an encryption algorithm, the code is not complete. But this should get you started:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)) {
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        txtPassword.Text = DecryptFunction(text);

    }
}
```

This will open the file and read the file. `DecryptFunction` is the function that will decrypt the file contents. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a `StreamReader` to read the contents of the file and then run your decryption algorithm on the read data, before finally displaying the result in the Text box.

Remember that the encrypted file should be treated as binary data and so isn't really suitable for display directly into the text box.

The encrypted file wont have real, end of line characters so you can't use `ReadLine`, but must use `ReadToEnd()` or `Read(blocksize)` (use this if your encryption process is not performed on the file as a whole, but data of a known size).